# What does an _ (underline character) on the left side of a C# lambda operator mean?

Tags: c#, lambda

What does an _ (underline character) on the left side of a C# lambda operator mean? as in:

```
        Movment = this.FixedUpdateAsObservable()
        .Select(_ =>
            {
                var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                return new Vector2(x, y).normalized;
            }
        );
```

Comment: It's a variable name, just like any other valid identifier would be in that position.

Comment: Some name the parameter that way to indicate that the parameter will not be used in the body of the lambda.  Otherwise, it's a parameter like any other.

Comment: Couldn't () be used instead? as in: () => {  }

Answer (score 0):

`_` is when you don't need the variable, it's there to allow the code to run.

Examples:

```
.Select(_ => ...
.Where(_ => ....
.OrderBy(_ =>
```

Comment: You've missed the point of the question.

Comment: @sstan Okay I updated my answer.